# Flutter: How to animate only the current page on page transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

So I have a Singin Page that I want to slides out when I navigate from Singin Page to my Home Page, and that slides in when I navigate from Home Page to Singin Page.

I was able to create the slide in animation like this:

```
Route slideInSignin() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const SigninPage(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const curve = Curves.ease;
      const from = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const to = Offset.zero;

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(
          Tween(begin: from, end: to).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve))
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I've seen guides that animates both page (slides first out as slides second in), I've tried to modify it but wihout success.

```
class SlideOutSingin extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget enterPage;
  final Widget exitPage;
  SlideOutSingin({required this.exitPage, required this.enterPage})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              enterPage,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                ).animate(animation),
                child: exitPage,
              ),
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
                child: enterPage,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
}
```

I don't want a full slide animation, I want to slide only the Signin Page (current) out so it feels like the Singin Page is a overlay that slides in and out from the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the guide to animate both pages is the answer, but it was not resulting in the expected behaviour because of the Stack order, that the later have priority of display, so if the enterPage is static and the exitPage is animating out of the way, the exitPage needs to have the priority, so it needs to be the later widget.

```
class SlideOutSingin extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget enterPage;
  final Widget exitPage;
  SlideOutSingin({required this.exitPage, required this.enterPage})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              enterPage,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
                child: enterPage,
              ),
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                ).animate(animation),
                child: exitPage,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
}
```